# machine learning and neural network - hidden layers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

you have been hired by a gem mining company to develop a classification system that can classify gems as part of the automated sorting system.

you decided to use a network with one hidden layer. how would you go about determining the best number of hidden units to use in this layer

Comment: What does the input data look like? Is it an image or a set of quality variables? Why did you decide to use just one hidden layer?

Comment: in input data is color - Represented by RGB component between 0.0 and 1.0 for each color. brightness - between 0.0 and 1.0. flaws 0 to 10 worst. the quality grade ranges  from A(best) b, c  and D(worst)

Answer (score 0):

Since that is very little information to go on, assuming the 1 hidden layer is fixed, i would start with `n_hidden = max(n_in, n_out)` neurons in the layer and then both increase and then decrease the neurons in steps all while monitoring the relevant metric using cross validation. The basic formula comes from *Introduction to Neural Networks with Java* by *Jeff Heaton* and has served me well so far.